# Механизм .gitignore, но без потери файла

Tags: git

Есть необходимость на проекте, чтобы у всех был файл, клонировался новым пользователям, но его изменения не виделись, как будто он был в .gitignore

Живой пример, файл где хранятся персональные логины для каждого из сотрудников - файл должен быть у всех, но данные там разные для каждого. Как сделать, чтобы он не лез в индекс, но при git clone людям заливалась его версия с пустыми полями?

Answer (score 2):

залить на гит файл с пустыми полями, в .gitignore добавить этот файл. Если файл уже в `.gitignore` `git add -f filename` - добавит текущую версию файла на гит.

Еще есть вариант добавить файл (н-д `.env.example`) который переименовуют в `.env` с которого уже используются актуальные настройки

Comment: Залил на гит файл с пустыми полями. Запушил. Добавил в гитигнор файл. Сделал в нем изменения.  Всё равно гит проиндексировал файл, вероятно потому что он уже был в индексе когда был с пустыми полями.

Comment: `git rm filename` вам поможет, а вообще это должен быть другой репозиторий, чистый, для деплоя. Могу поделиться [нашими наработками](https://github.com/ClnViewer/Split-post-commit-Hook---SVN-GIT-HG) в области поддержки 'очищенных' репозиториев :)